# Connect to MySQL through command line without using root password?

Tags: linux, mysql, bash, postgresql, shell-scripting

I'm building a Bash script for some tasks. One of those tasks is create a MySQL DB from within the same bash script. What I'm doing right now is creating two vars: one for store user name and the other for store password. This is the relevant part of my script:

```
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=mypass_goes_here

touch /tmp/$PROY.sql && echo "CREATE DATABASE $DB_NAME;" > /tmp/script.sql
mysql --user=$MYSQL_USER --password="$MYSQL_PASS" < /tmp/script.sql
rm -rf /tmp/script.sql
```

But always get a error saying access denied for user root with NO PASSWORD, what I'm doing wrong? I need to do the same for PostgreSQL.

Comment: Do some debugging (-: Try `echo "$MYSQL_PASS"` before you pass it to the `mysql` line. Does it have the correct password?

Comment: Can you login as usual without the script?

Comment: **-h** is missing. It is also not a good idea to put passwords on a command-line, since they will be visible for everyone calling `ps wwaux`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Both for MySQL and PostgreSQL you can specify your user and password in local config file. .my.cnf for MySQL and .pgpass for PostgreSQL. These files should be in your home directory (i.e. ~/.my.cnf).

.my.cnf:

```
[mysql]
user=user
password=password
```

.pgpass:

```
host:port:database:user:password
```

You can have a wildcard entry here, substituting any field for *******.

PS: **DO NOT EVER SPECIFY A PASSWORD ON THE COMMAND LINE!** This can be perfectly visible with **ps** if your system is not configured to not show processes that belongs to other users.

@thinice: If you want to create those files really secure you should do:

```
umask 077
touch .my.new.config
umask 022 # or whatever was your default
```

This way the file would be created with secure permissions from the start and no eavesdropper would have a chance leeching your password.

PostgreSQL will refuse to use the file with permissions higher the 0600 anyway.

Comment: For mysql the mysql client you can point at a specific config file with `--defaults-extra-file=filename`.  This might be useful if you want to place it somewhere non-standard, or just create a temporary file.  Is suspect their is a similar option with PostgreSQL, but I am not familiar with that.

Comment: And for the love of happy gilmore's shorts chmod that file `0600`

Comment: @kworr I'll aready try that but my MySQL doesn't start changing this parameters at /etc/my.cnf :( didn't know the cause. I'll try again later

Comment: It's not the /etc/my.cnf. Updating answer.

Comment: @kworr I try your solution but doesn't work at all. The DB is created by empty and doesn't appear in phpMyAdmin or any other GUI tool. I set the data directory in /etc/my.cnf to datadir=/data/var/lib/mysql and set permissions to 0755 at /data/var/lib/mysql and also owner to mysql:mysql, why the database is empty? where is the problem?

Comment: @kworr and for the PostgreSQL sentence, if I'll create the DB and not connect to, what's the correct sentence?

Comment: (1) Why you are changing datadir? MySQL server process has already populated his own one, you can't create your database in another directory. (2) I can't decipher what you say about PostgreSQL. Showing some logs with errors would help.

Comment: @kworr (1) I want the directory data in another external HDD  and not in system HDD for that reason I change the datadir. (2) For the PostgreSQL part, you said before I need to create a .pgpass file but this .pgpass sentence contains a database parameter, If I want to create a database like I does with MySQL and not to connect, what will be the correct command?

Comment: (1) That's beyond the scope of the question but if you want your datadir reside on another disk you should move it there when server is not running. (2) And again .pgpass file is only about authentication, it's not about creating database. You should create db with CREATE DATABASE.

Comment: What if there are is more than one user/password combination ? I would look for a way to supply the answer to -p in the command... -uuser -p db. I I tried a HERE doc (<<Label  ) but that does not work for a password

Answer (score 4):

```
mysql_config_editor set --login-path=storedPasswordKey --host=localhost --user=root --password
```

How do I execute a command line with a secure password??
use the config editor!!!

As of mysql 5.6.6 you can store the password in a config file and then execute cli commands like this....

```
mysql --login-path=storedPasswordKey ....
```

--login-path replaces variables... host, user AND password.
excellent right!

Comment: http://blog.geekslikeshinythings.com/2015/02/mysql-cli-password-mysqlconfigeditor.html

Comment: Thanks for sharing! There's just one gotcha from this approach. The parameter --login-path has to be the first parameter of the call or else you are going to get the "unknown variable 'login-path=local'" message.

Answer (score 2):

Don't put quotes around the password because if you do the quotes are considered to be part of the password.

Answer (score 2):

```
MYSQL_USER="root"
MYSQL_PASSWORD="PASSWORD"
DBNAME="DB_NAME"

mysql -u$MYSQL_USER -p$MYSQL_PASSWORD -e "CREATE DATABASE $DBNAME;" 2> /tmp/error1

STATUS=$? 
if [ $STATUS -eq 0 ];
then 
    echo -e "Database '$DBNAME' is created"
elif (grep -i "^ERROR 1007" /tmp/error1 > /dev/null);
then
    echo -e "Database '$DBNAME' already exists"
else
    echo -e "Failed to create database '$DBNAME'"
fi

rm -r /tmp/error1
```

This will do the trick
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9293042/1213346) exists on StackOverflow.

To summarize [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34670902/1213346) from there.

You can `export MYSQL_PWD=yourverysecretpassword`.

The upside of this method over using a configuration file is that you do not need a separate configuration file to keep in sync with your script. You only have the script to maintain.

There is **no downside** to this method.

The password is **not** visible to other users on the system (it would be visible if it is on the command line). The environment variables are only visible to the user running the mysql command, and root.

The password will also be visible to anyone who can read the script itself, so make sure the script itself is protected. This is in no way different than protecting a configuration file. You can still source the password from a separate file if you want to have the script publicly readable (`export MYSQL_PWD=$(cat /root/mysql_password)` for example). It is still easier to export a variable than to build a configuration file.

E.g.,

```
$ export MYSQL_PWD=xoF3mafn5Batxasdfuo
$ mysqldump -u root mysql | head
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.6.23, for Linux (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: mysql
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.6.23
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
MYSQL_USER="root"
MYSQL_PASS="mypass_goes_here"

touch /tmp/$PROY.sql && echo "CREATE DATABASE $DB_NAME;" > /tmp/script.sql
mysql --user=$MYSQL_USER --password=$MYSQL_PASS < /tmp/script.sql
rm -rf /tmp/script.sql
```

be sure how you write your pass and it doesn't escape

--defaults-extra-file= is a good thing (tm) (c)